# Reusing alias for an expression in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do this:

```
select first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name, Length(full_name) as len from customer order by len
```

It is not possible;

> column "full_name" does not exist

So, I have to do this:

```
select first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name, Length(first_name || ' ' || last_name) as len from customer order by len
```

Does it mean sql engine has to compute expression 'first_name || ' ' || last_name' two times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observe, what you want to do is not possible.  Instead, you can use a lateral join to calculate values in the `FROM` clause:

```
select v.full_name, Length(v.full_name) as len
from customer c cross join lateral
     (values (first_name || ' ' || last_name)
     ) v(full_name)
order by len;
```

Comment: Does it mean we can't pass aliases to functions()?

Comment: @Mandroid . . . No, it means that you cannot re-use an alias in the same `select` (or `where`) that defines it.  You could use a CTE or subquery as well.